# How to use a non-default login shell for ssh login

Tags: shell, ssh, login

I am currently working in a network that uses LDAP for authentication. Having set `zsh` as my login shell, I ran into a problem of gaining remote access through `ssh` to one of the machines on the network that, apparently, doesn't have `zsh` installed. The login fails with

`Dec  8 19:16:11 abert sshd[20649]: User sorokine not allowed because shell /bin/zsh does not exist`

So the question basically is: How can I tell the remote machine to use a different login shell than the one that was configured in LDAP?

OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Comment: Have you considered changing your LDAP shell to something more universal such as `/bin/sh` and then have your remote `~/.profile` exec the appropriate shell if available?

Comment: That would be an option, but not a very clean one, so I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993598/ssh-then-change-shell

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your login shell can't be executed on some machine, then you can't log into it over SSH, or by most other methods for that matter. The SSH server always executes your login shell. If you pass a command on the `ssh` command line then the login shell is executed with `-c` and the command string¹ as arguments; otherwise the login shell is executed as a login shell with no argument.

If there was a way to bypass the login shell, that would be a security hole. An account can be configured as a restricted account by making its login shell a program that only performs one specific task; for example, the login shell could be [`git-shell`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) to allow only access to a git repository, or [`rssh`](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/), etc.

To log in to that machine, you'll need to either arrange for `/bin/zsh` to be present, or change your login shell to something that is present.

What I recommend in a heterogeneous environment like this is to stick to `/bin/sh` as your login shell, because it's present everywhere. Set the `SHELL` environment variable to `/bin/zsh` if it's present, that way you'll get zsh as an interactive shell.

```
if [ -x /bin/zsh ]; then
  export SHELL=/bin/zsh
fi
```

While you're at it, this lets you avoid hard-coding the path to `zsh`.

```
if SHELL=$(command -v zsh); then
  export SHELL
else
  unset SHELL
fi
```

To get zsh to run automatically for a text mode login, invoke it from your `.profile`. If you want to use `.zprofile` to set things up, make it a login shell (but then you won't get the same environment on machines where zsh isn't present, so I don't recommend this). Do this only if this is an interactive login, not when your `.profile` is executed by a script, during GUI mode login, etc.

```
if case $- in *i*) true;; *) false;; esac &&  # interactive shell
   [ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] &&                   # not running zsh yet
   type zsh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then      # zsh is present
  exec zsh
fi
```

¹  <sub>The SSH client concatenates its non-option arguments with spaces in between, and sends the resulting string through the connection. The SSH protocols defines the command as a string, not a list of strings.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Looks like it's the only way to go that doesn't involve installing zsh on the remote machine, and it works perfectly, so I'll stick to it.

Comment: I also suggest to add a test `[ "0$SHLVL" -lt 2 ]` in case the default login shell supports `$SHLVL` so that `bash -l` or another shell can be run if need be (e.g. in case zsh fails for some reason). Thus `ssh -t host bash -l` would run a `bash` login shell without executing zsh behind. Also, I would replace `exec zsh` by `exec zsh -l` so that the `.zlogin` file is sourced.

Answer (score 2):

You must ether install the shell on the specified machine if you have access in a different way or request it from an administrator to do this for you or change your shell in ldap to a shell that exists on the remote machine.

(open)sshd will *always* check for the user shell and it will *always* execute that shell whatever is passed to execute. If another shell is passed to execute it will execute it passing it as an argument to the user shell, for example the user shell is '/bin/sh' and you pass as an argument a csh shell than it will run "/bin/sh -c /bin/csh'.

Comment: Read redfast comment. openssh does allow you to bypass the default shell.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro If it did it kind of takes away the logic behind setting the shell to something like '/bin/false' or '/sbin/nologin'. If you're referring to changing the shell after login than ok, but it does it like I wrote above (sh -c othersh), if there's no '/bin/sh' than you're out of luck. (Tested on Redhat).

Comment: True indeed, if passwd has a shell that is not listed in /etc/shells, you wont login anyway. But if you are able to login, and unless sshd_config does not force you to a particular shell, any command that the user is capable of runnng is fair game.  If you do a couple more tests, for instance `ssh -l user server "ps ax" | grep bash` it is easy to notice the default shell is not *always* invoked. What it really prevents the other solution from working is the security check of zsh not being in /etc/shells

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro Run strace -f sshd on server side. You will see something like "execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "ps"]..." Also, /sbin/nologin is a valid shell in /etc/shells.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro redfast00's answer is plain wrong. nkms's is right.

Comment: nologin is not be by default in /etc/shells and should not be put there. I thought I had agreed redfast answer is wrong several phrases ago Giles. I will do the strace or a sysdig nkms. (does actually the strace work with privilege separation for that?). Nvmind, I will test.

Comment: I did the sysdig, and indeed bash is executed, no doubts there. However if it is a simple command it seems to be doing somethings slight different from "bash -c ps"...the PID remains the same actually for the new command, which does agree with the fact a ps wont see bash running. will investigate it more.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro In Redhat, /sbin/nologin is in /etc/shells for over a decade: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53963